# Python: Is there a way to overlay a matplot color map graph over a GeoDataFrame map plot using latitude and longitude coordinates?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, geopandas

I have a GeoData frame (created from a shape file) that contains latitude and longitude coordinates for all of the counties in the United States. When graphed, it displays the map with all of the county outlines drawn.

I have another set of values with Lat/Long coordinates that I am running a KNN algorithm on to generate a color map. Is there a way to overlay the color map onto the GeoData frame map?

I have tried just plotting them at the same time:

```
df_usa.plot()
mplot.scatter(x, y, c=approx_values, cmap='viridis)
mplot.show()
```

But this plots the color map far from where the geomap is in the map frame.

Any advice on how to do this is greatly appreciated. I am using geopandas, pandas, and shapely on Python 3.7.

Comment: Are you sure both spatial objects share the same `crs` ?

Comment: I am not sure, that is something to check. How do I do that?

Comment: You can use `crs` method. For instance, `df_usa.crs`.